# Run spring boot with jdk9 using jigsaw modules

Tags: java, spring, java-9, java-platform-module-system

What's wrong with this application. I thought the mix of classpath jars and module jars are valid. For all jars not having an explicit module-info become an automatic module? When I delete my module-info.java it works. Because IDEA using the classpath for this case.

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+176)

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4

module-info.java

```
module test {
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.boot;
}
```

App.java

```
package com.foo.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.foo.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
    </parent>

    <name>test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot
>   instantiate interface
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer :
>   org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer
>     at
>   spring.boot@2.0.0.M2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:439)
>     at
>   spring.boot@2.0.0.M2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:418)
>     at
>   spring.boot@2.0.0.M2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:409)
>     at
>   spring.boot@2.0.0.M2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:266)
>     at
>   spring.boot@2.0.0.M2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:247)
>     at
>   spring.boot@2.0.0.M2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245)
>     at
>   spring.boot@2.0.0.M2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233)
>     at test/com.foo.test.App.main(App.java:10) Caused by:
>   **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException**     at
>   spring.beans@5.0.0.RC2/org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:145)
>     at
>   spring.boot@2.0.0.M2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:435)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   java.sql.SQLException     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
>     ... 9 more

Comment: It is highly recommended to name your module according to your package. For example `module com.foo.test {...}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume spring.boot is an automatic module. An automatic module doesn't declare it dependences so you have to use `--add-modules` to ensure that any explicit modules needed are resolved. If spring.boot were an explicit module then I assume it would `requires java.sql` and you won't have this issue.

Comment: vm argument: --add-modules=java.sql also works but that is not would you mean?

Comment: Yes, I meant `--add-modules=java.sql` to ensure that the java.sql module is resolved. It will not otherwise be resolved because no module requires it. You have worked around it by adding `requires java.sql` to your module but that should not be needed (and won't be needed once spring.boot is migrated to an explicit module).

Comment: Alex Buckley told us at devoxxUS (Modular Development with JDK 9) automatic modules: "... Requires everything, they require each other, they require all modules in the jdk image and they require all of your modules as well, and they export their packages..." (The quote is similar what he said). I still don't get it why I have to add the java.sql module. And anyway when it's necessary why only java.sql? I'm pretty sure spring.boot has some more. Is requires and "declare dependences" not the same?

Answer (score 5):

finally, I got it... my module-info have to look like this:

```
module test {
    requires java.sql; // my real problem solved with this
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.boot;
    exports com.foo.test; // subsequent error 1: beeing accessible for some spring modules
    opens com.foo.test to spring.core; // subsequent error 2: beeing accessible for spring.core in a deep reflection way
}
```

Can someone explain why I have to requires java.sql; inside my own module when I don't use it?

Comment: because java.sql is required by `spring`. Since `spring` is automatic module it does not declare what it needs to work, so you need to include java.sql to the module graph either by `--add-modules java.sql` or by `requires java.sql` in your own module

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when upgraded from Java 8 to Java 11.

Solved by selecting different option in Intellij run configuration:
[image: shorten command line]

Answer (score -2):

This is almost certainly because you are missing the jdbc driver jar for MySql. you need to use this dependency :-

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```