# Couldn't find type java.sql.Date. Are you missing a dependency on your classpath? while i try to run test

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to run my application in Spring Boot using MariaDB with spring-data but I can't because IntelliJ shows me this error during build:

```
Error:java: Couldn't find type java.sql.Date. Are you missing a dependency on your classpath?
```

Here you can see [pom.xml](https://ideone.com/riBWBR)

[I found one way to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54793087/couldnt-find-type-java-sql-date-are-you-missing-a-dependency-on-your-classpath), but using it, I can`t run tests normally

Comment: If you run the tests via the command line does the problem still exist? This will tell you if its an intellij issue or a maven issue.

Comment: this kind of thing can sometimes be resolved by running the maven reimport function in intellij, also do you still get the issue if you run the maven goal "verify" (I suspect not)

Comment: Are you use java 9 modules? Note that `java.sql` package needs to be explicitly imported in JDK 9+ versions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362463/java-9-modules-noclassdeffounderror-java-sql-date and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910768/run-spring-boot-with-jdk9-using-jigsaw-modules

Comment: @Andrey I use java 9

Comment: @Deadron when I run tests the command line, I don`t have this problem. But I need to run it with IntelliJ for debug

Comment: As was suggested above reimport your project into intellij. If it succeeded on the command line you know there is no issue with your project just that intellij is out of sync.